# Как на линуксе скопировать все файлы из одного каталога в другой, с переименованием файлов с одинаковым названием?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль

Linux Ubuntu 18.04
Имеется каталог, допустим papka1, нужно все файлы из этого каталога скопировать в другой, предположим papka2. Если имеются файлы с одинаковыми именами, то при копировании изменить имя, добавив к нему «.1», например, file.c скопировать в file.c.1
Команда 'cp' позволяет копировать разом все файлы, но не могу понять как сохранить оба(там выбор либо перезаписать либо нет)
В идеале сделать это вообще без команды 'cp', может быть через цикл 'for'?

Answer (score 3):

```
cp -r --backup=t papka1/* papka2
```

будет добавляться `.~1~` `.~2~` и т.д.

Comment: тоже думал об этом, смущает наличие ~
Плюс просветите, пожалуйста, резервная копия отличается чем-то от исходного файла?
Примечание
чтобы скопировать содержимое каталога, а не сам каталог, надо после названия исходного каталога добавить '/.'

Comment: в целом это хорошее решение, единственное что создание резервной копии не совсем то, что требуется

Comment: Так как по условию обе директории существуют, то необходимо добавить звездочку в исходную директорию: `cp -r --backup=t papka1/* papka2`, в противном случае на выходе создается `papka2/papka1`.

Answer (score 2):

например, с помощью программы `rsync` с опциями `--backup` (`-b`) и `--suffix=`.

демонстрация:

```
$ mkdir 1 2
$ echo 123 > 1/1
$ echo 456 > 2/1
$ find -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
d2d362cdc6579390f1c0617d74a7913d  ./2/1
ba1f2511fc30423bdbb183fe33f3dd0f  ./1/1
$ rsync -r --backup --suffix=.1 1/ 2/
$ find -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
ba1f2511fc30423bdbb183fe33f3dd0f  ./2/1
d2d362cdc6579390f1c0617d74a7913d  ./2/1.1
ba1f2511fc30423bdbb183fe33f3dd0f  ./1/1
```

как видим, предыдущее содержимое файла `2/1` было сохранено в файле `2/1.1`

Comment: а что с кодом, там 5 длинных наборов символов вместо команд, это что?

Comment: не понял, о каком коде и каких наборах символов речь.

Comment: '
$ find -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
d2d362cdc6579390f1c0617d74a7913d  ./2/1
ba1f2511fc30423bdbb183fe33f3dd0f  ./1/1
$ rsync -r --backup --suffix=.1 1/ 2/
$ find -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
ba1f2511fc30423bdbb183fe33f3dd0f  ./2/1
d2d362cdc6579390f1c0617d74a7913d  ./2/1.1
ba1f2511fc30423bdbb183fe33f3dd0f  ./1/1
'

Comment: грубо говоря после каждой команды find наборы символов вида: d2d362cdc6579390f1c0617d74a7913d

Comment: так это md5-суммы. команда `find -type f -exec md5sum {} \;` находит в текущем каталоге все файлы и для каждого выполняет программу md5sum. а ниже вывод, состящий из контрольной суммы и имени файла.

Comment: а, да, разобрался, спасибо

Comment: именно то, что нужно было

Answer (score 2):

еще как вариант вместо простой нумерации привязать к времени создания дубля

Создадим полигон:

```
$ rm -rf test; mkdir -p test/{1,2}; touch test/1/{a..d};touch test/2/{c..f}; tree test
test
├── 1
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   ├── c
│   └── d
└── 2
    ├── c
    ├── d
    ├── e
    └── f

2 directories, 8 files
```

копируем:

```
$ cp -r --suffix=".$(date '+%s').bak" test/1/* test/2; tree test
test
├── 1
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   ├── c
│   └── d
└── 2
    ├── a
    ├── b
    ├── c
    ├── c.1665145369.bak
    ├── d
    ├── d.1665145369.bak
    ├── e
    └── f

2 directories, 12 files
```

при желании всегда можно перевести время командой

```
$ date -d@1665145369
Пт 07 окт 2022 15:22:49 EEST
```